# How to select data rows from MySQL if i have few date rows separately?

Tags: mysql

i have

1. day     column,
2. month   column,
3. year    column,
4. content1 column,
5. content2 column,

example:

1. day   12
2. month 6
3. year  2015

What query i need to select all rows between 10/03/2014 and 03/04/2015 for example? The problem is that i have days and month separately. I need to extract all content1 and content2 regarding two dates.

Comment: I need to extract all content1 and content2 regarding two dates.

Comment: I mean what query have you tried before for trying it?

Comment: I have to ask - why did you use 3 separate columns to store the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL this query will work

```
SELECT content1,content2 FROM the_table 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(month, '/', day, '/', year), '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '10/03/2014' AND '03/04/2015';
```

Hope that helps you out

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Date` or `Datetime` and spare yourself of the grief that would otherwise follow

```
drop table theGuy;

create table theGuy
(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    fullName varchar(60) not null,
    birthDate date not null
);

insert theGuy (fullName,birthDate) values ('Kim Smithers','2002-3-1'),('John Doe','2014-4-5');

select * from theGuy where birthDate>='2000-1-1' and birthDate<='2007-12-31';

select * from theGuy where birthDate between '2000-1-1' and '2007-12-31';


select *,birthDate+interval 45 DAY as BirthCertAvail from theGuy;

select *,datediff(curdate(),birthDate) as DaysAlive from theGuy;
```

You might find the built-in routines adequate, such as intervals, without having to rewrite them. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    my_table
HAVING
    CONVERT(CONCAT(year, '-', month, '-', day), DATE) BETWEEN '2014-10-03' AND '2015-03-04';(Year||' '||Day||' '||Month, 'YYYY DD MM') BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```